# Squash image into window, unless window is bigger than image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Okay, so I've got an image in the body of my webpage.

If the user's window height is less than 800px (the height of the image), the image should be squashed into it (so that the user can see the whole height of the image).

If, on the other hand, the window height is greater than 800px, the image should be vertically centred.

Any tippers?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm quite horrible at anything that isn't basic javascript/css/html, so nothing other than playing around with css.

Comment: check my small answer giving you a hint on what you could do... positioning depends on what you want to achieve... only position it in the middle of window is not enough > what if the user scrolls then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using jQuery you could do something like:

```
var win = $(window);
win.load(function() {
  var image = $("#img");
  if (image.height() > win.height()) {
    image.height(win.height());
  } else {
    // assuming your image is positioned absolute
    // you should measure its dimensions and then position it
    // depends on the ways it should be centered... in the current window or the whole document?
  }
});

win.resize(function() { /* do something */ });
```

should do the trick to just resize the image to the height of the window if the image is bigger the selector needs to be adapted for your image element of course...

EDIT: added resize callback

Comment: That's great! My only question is: do I need to use setInterval to keep checking this just incase they change the window size? Or is there some trigger i can use, like "onWindowDimensionChange()"?

Comment: see the edited code... win.resize apllies an event listener to the "resize" event fired by the browser... be careful, IE7 sometimes triggers resize event if the DOM changes, so your code could run into loops (depending on the HTML / CSS)